# How to Export sccm reports?

Tags: powershell, export, report, sccm

Im trying to export sccm reports automatically using powershell or anything else.
Can someone please advise me how to do that?

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For anyone who need help on this, I've found a solution: using the UI of sccm I've managed to obtain a full report in XML format, I scheduled a daily export with the parameters needed using the sccm interface and parsed the output. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use one ODBC connection on the DB server with Acces and extract information